# cannot clone database to a different sql server

Tags: azure, powershell

I'm trying to clone an existing Azure SQL DB  to a SQL server in a different region.  I use the powershell script

```
Restore-AzSqlDatabase -FromPointInTimeBackup -PointInTime (Get-Date) -ResourceGroupName $TargetRGName -ServerName $TargetServerName -TargetDatabaseName $TargetDBName -ResourceId $Database.ResourceID
```

But I get the error : Long running operation failed with status 'Failed'.

Comment: you'd need to provide the actual error, you can get it from the activity log, I assume

Answer (score 0):

Restores can only be done to an instance of a SQL Server in the same Azure region without using the `-FromGeoBackup` flag.  `-FromGeoBackup` Indicates that this cmdlet restores a SQL database from a geo-redundant backup. You can use the `Get-AzSqlDatabaseGeoBackup` cmdlet to get a geo-redundant backup.  The target region MUST be the paired region for the source.  You can find the paired regions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/best-practices-availability-paired-regions).

If you wish to move the database to another region that is not the pair, you can create a failover group to replicate the target to another region.  Once fully replicated, you can break the failover group and delete the source DB.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-move-resources-across-regions